# Why is the button floating up before going down?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, framer-motion

[image]

I wanted the button to move down to accomodate for a new row added. So I put `layout` on the `MotionButton` (Which is just a `motion(...)` wrapped component).

```
<div className="grid gap-5">
  <AnimatePresence>
    {flightDates.map((f, index) => (
      <motion.div
        key={index}
        exit={{
          opacity: 0,
          y: 10,
        }}
        initial={{
          opacity: 0,
          y: 10,
        }}
        animate={{
          opacity: 1,
          y: 0,
        }}
        transition={{
          duration: 0.2,
        }}
      >
        <FlightDateRow
          key={index}
          onChange={(updatedFlight) => {
            setFlightDates((prev) => {
              const newFlights = [...prev]
              newFlights[index] = {
                ...newFlights[index],
                ...updatedFlight,
              }
              return newFlights
            })
          }}
          onDelete={removeFlightDate(index)}
          canDelete={flightDates.length > 1}
          {...f}
        />
      </motion.div>
    ))}
  </AnimatePresence>
  <MotionButton
    className="w-min pl-2"
    variant="secondary"
    onClick={addNewFlightDate}
    layout
    transition={{
      duration: 0.2,
    }}
  >
    <PlusMini className="mr-2" />
    Flight
  </MotionButton>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add `useEffect(() => { console.log("button mounted"); return () => console.log("button unmounted"); }, [])` to your `MotionButton` component to validate that the button is not for some reason re-mounted. Which causes the button to trigger its end animation followed by its initial animation. It's fine if the logs display when you load the button, but they should not display whenever you click the button. What is the output of the above? Is your button re-mounted whenever you click the button?

Comment: @3limin4t0r Yes it appears you're right, my button is being re-mounted. When the button is clicked, the console prints out "button mounted" then "button unmounted" and then once again "button mounted". Is this why my animation is like this?

Comment: I am also using the `layout` prop instead of `exit` and `initial` on the button. But is that how layout is working under the hood either way?

Comment: Oh snap. It definitely is my weird button component. I created a basic framer html button and that appears to work perfectly. If you happen to have time, here is my button component. I'm not sure why it's causing re-mounting when it's clicked. https://gist.github.com/StephenSHorton/e9a4363edf13a4ae46786912127b16ce

Comment: @3limin4t0r I managed to solve it with that hint. I wrapped my button in a motion div instead and it's working. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked you in the comments if you could add the following debugging statement:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("button mounted");
  return () => console.log("button unmounted");
}, []);
```

Because I suspected you're component was being re-mounted. This would explain the behaviour, since your button would trigger its unmount animation, and then its mount animation.

You confirmed this was indeed the case:

> Yes it appears you're right, my button is being re-mounted. When the button is clicked, the console prints out "button mounted" then "button unmounted" and then once again "button mounted".

Since you haven't provided much context in the question I can only guess why it's being re-mounted. Here is a scenario that is probably the most common.

---

Say though some sort of logic the structure of you output JSX changes from:

```
<A>
  <YourButton />
</A>
```

to:

```
<B>
  <YourButton />
</B>
```

This causes `<A>` to unmount, which in turn causes all the children of `<A>` also unmount. Then `<B>` is mounted with all its children. Due to the parent component change of `YourButton`, `YourButton` will also be unmounted and mounted.

```js
function Demo() {
  const [useA, setUseA] = React.useState(true);
  const toggleUseA = React.useCallback(() => setUseA(useA => !useA), []);
  
  const Wrapper = useA ? A : B;

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggleUseA}>use {useA ? "B" : "A"}</button>
      <Wrapper><YourButton /></Wrapper>
    </div>
  );
}

const A = ({ children }) => <div>A{children}</div>;
const B = ({ children }) => <div>B{children}</div>;

function YourButton() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("YourButton mounted");
    return () => console.log("YourButton unmounted");
  }, []);
  
  return null;
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")).render(<Demo />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I don't know if this is the exact cause, since there are other reasons why a component might re-mount. But this is in my opinion the most likely cause. It could be be the internals of Framer Motion it could be something else.

I hope this helps you understand why this problem happens and are happy to see you already found a solution to your issue in your own answer.

---

ps. After looking at your gist it seems like you're doing the exact thing I describe above. See: [gist line 49-57](https://gist.github.com/StephenSHorton/e9a4363edf13a4ae46786912127b16ce#file-button-tsx-L49-L57)

> ```
> const Comp = asChild ? Slot : 'button'
>
> ...
>
> return (
>   <Comp
>     ...
>   >
>     {children}
>   </Comp>
> )
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to wrap my button in a `<motion.div layout></motion.div>` instead of converting the button to a `MotionButton`. My button component would cause a remount to occur when clicking the button. So relying on an outer div to manage position within the layout fixed it.